# as3 flash gotoAndPlay

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash, event-handling

I am making a small platformer game at flash and I just added the first enemy.
I get this in the "output":

" TypeError: Error #1006: gotoAndPlay is not a function.
    at scratch_theGame_nojumping_tryEnemy_fla::MainTimeline/fl_enemyAlerted() "

My code on the enemy layer is the following:

```
var enemyAlerted:Boolean = false;
var alerted:Boolean = false;
var enemy:Object = new Object();

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_alerted);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_enemyAlerted);

function fl_alerted(event:Event):void
{
    if (char.x > 400)
    {
        alerted = true;
    }
}
function fl_enemyAlerted(event:Event):void
{
    if (alerted = false)
    {
        enemy.gotoAndPlay("alert");
    }
    if (alerted = true)
    {
        enemy.gotoAndPlay("chase");
    }
}
```

My goal here is to make the enemy loop the 'alert' animation from the start until my character has come close enough to be noticed, and then the enemy should play the 'chase' animation. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your **enemy** variable is just an empty non-specific **Object**, not a **MovieClip**, thus **enemy.gotoAndPlay** is not a member of the **enemy**, hence it is **null**, hence you are calling **null()** which is not a good thing to do.

Comment: @Organis does this mean that it's my var declaration that is wrong or the object should be a movie clip?

Comment: That means that you are trying to access the wrong instance. You (probably) have a **MovieClip** designed there on stage/timeline, but instead you are accessing some meaningless variable you declared in your script.